# How to make multiple ranges or group data in QlikView?

Tags: qlikview

I am trying to group data in qlik view

Like if I have the following set

Value Number

F0 1

F1 4

F2 2

F3 4

F4 5

F5 1

So I wanna sum them like this

If Value contains (F1 or F2) Sum in Group 1

If Value contains (F3 or F4) Sum in Group 2

If Value contains (F5) Sum in Group 3

How can I do this qlikView.

Thanks

Comment: Is this in a front end object or in the  data load script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I was able to do this using the following

Add a Calculated Dimension with the following Expression

```
=If(Match(Time,'F4','F5','F6','F7','F8','F9','F10','F11'),'Morning',
If(Match(Time,'F12','F13','F14','F15','F16'),'Afternoon',
If(Match(Time,'F17','F18','F19','F20'),'Evening','Others')))
```

Hope it helps somebody